# How to HTTP GET a text file from the gcloud server using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, http-get

I'm trying to use the $.get("publicURL") in javascript to get a text file from a gcloud server in app engine but its not working. I generated a public URL for the text file and it downloads the file when I access the link via my browser: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/yarab-201209.appspot.com/hello_default.txt?_ga=2.246296516.-1902376398.1523704795". Also, I have a local apache server and it works ok when I use  $.get("file.txt", function(txt)) but I want to do it on the gcloud. What is wrong with what I'm doing? I have little knowledge in coding .

Edit: This is my complete code thats working on the local server but I know the problem is with the $.get part. I want to use the same code on gcloud. I'm creating an active google maps server that receive the location remotely.

```
<?php
$file = 'gps.txt';
if (!empty($_GET["latitude"]) && !empty($_GET["longitude"])) {

    function getParameter($par, $default = null){
        if (isset($_GET[$par]) && strlen($_GET[$par])) return $_GET[$par];
        elseif (isset($_POST[$par]) && strlen($_POST[$par])) 
            return $_POST[$par];
        else return $default;
    }


    $lat = getParameter("latitude");
    $lon = getParameter("longitude");
    $person = $lat.",".$lon."\n";

    echo "
        DATA:\n
        Latitude: ".$lat."\n
        Longitude: ".$lon;

    if (!file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX))
        echo "\n\t Error saving Data\n";
    else echo "\n\t Data Save\n";
}
else {
```

?>

```
<!-- Load Jquery -->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Google Maps Api -->

<!-- IMPORTANT: change the API v3 key -->

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=?????????"></script>
```

">

```
<!-- Initialize Map and markers -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(25.10045,55.17805);
    var marker;
    var map;
    var mapProp;

    function initialize()
    {
        mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:15,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
        setInterval('mark()',5000);
    }



    function mark()
    {
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var file = "gps.txt";

        $.get(file, function(txt) { 
            var lines = txt.split("\n");

            for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){

                console.log(lines[i]);
                var words=lines[i].split(",");

                if ((words[0]!="")&&(words[1]!="")){

                    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                          position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]),
                          });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]));

                }
            }
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```
    <!-- Draw information table and Google Maps div -->

    <div>
        <center><br />
            <b> SIM908 GPS position DEMO </b><br /><br />
            <div id="superior" style="width:800px;border:1px solid">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Satellites</td>
                        <td>Speed OTG</td>
                        <td>Course</td>
                                                    <td>lat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="time">'. date("Y M d - H:m") .'</td>
                        <td id="sat"></td>
                        <td id="speed"></td>
                        <td id="course"></td>
                                                     <td id="latitude"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:700px;"></div>
        </center>
    </div>';
?>
```

Comment: Please define "_it's not working_".

Comment: Can you check the developer console of your browser for errors? Sounds like the cross origin policy to me.

Comment: Please add the relevant code, and explain in details what you want to do, what goes wrong and possible error messages.

Comment: The console shows an error on the .$get("https://storage.googleapis.com/yarab-201209.appspot.com/hello_default.txt", function(txt)) line. As I mentioned the $.get("file.txt", function(txt)) works okay with the local server. Is it it wrong to put a website url in the get request?

Comment: @Teemu I edited my question to include the whole code but I know the problem is with the $.get part

Comment: What the error message says?

Comment: This is the error I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
When I change my jquery src from the local file I upload when I deploy my app to "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" , the error goes and I get this one instead on the same line: "Failed to load http://yarab-201209.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/hello_default.txt: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."